# How can I change the directory that "cd \" goes to in git?

Tags: windows, dos

When I enter `cd \` git goes into a different directory than I would like to.

How can I change it so that `cd \` takes me to

```
C:\Users\J P\Dropbox\Git Bash
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cd \` takes you to the root directory of the current drive. That is a function of Windows, not a function of `git`.

If you want to change it, you'll have to use Windows to do that, not `git`.

One route might be to use a separate drive letter (e.g. `Z:`) bound to `C:\Users\J P\Dropbox\Git Bash`. In DOS the [`SUBST` command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUBST) did that. It appears to work with [XP](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/subst.mspx?mfr=true), and [here's](https://superuser.com/questions/29072/how-to-make-subst-mapping-persistent-across-reboots) a way to make it persistent. The easiest appears to be:

```
 net use z: "\\computerName\c$\Users\J P\Dropbox\Git Bash" /persistent:yes
```

Then if you change to drive `z:`, `cd \` will take you to `z:`'s root, which will be the right place.

There's probably a different/better Windows way to do that.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other command in git that takes me to "C:\Users\J P\Dropbox\Git Bash". "C:\Users\J P\Dropbox\Git Bash" is also the directory I start git from.

Comment: No. How would git know which repo's root to change to? You could set up a DOS alias I suppose: http://superuser.com/questions/560519/how-to-set-an-alias-in-windows-command-line